# Searching LDAP from Jenkins scripted pipeline

Tags: jenkins, groovy

we store a GitHub account in one of the AD User attribute. When receiving a Pull Request webhook from GitHub I want to find a user based on GitHub Account and notify user about tests results. How to do that?

Answer (score 1):

if I understand you correctly you want to take email attribute value by another user attribute. can't test the following code but it should give you an idea how to do that.

```
import javax.naming.directory.InitialDirContext
import javax.naming.directory.DirContext

Properties ldapProps = [
    'java.naming.factory.initial'        :'com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory',
    'java.naming.security.authentication':'simple',
    'java.naming.provider.url'           :'ldap://ldap-host:389',
    'java.naming.security.principal'     :'ldap-access-username',
    'java.naming.security.credentials'   :'ldap-access-password',
] as Properties


String user          = 'user-to-search'
String attr          = 'mail'           //attribute name for email could be different in your ldap
String ldapFilter    = "CN=${user}"     //put instead of `CN` git attribute
String[] attrValues  = []               //array because could be several values for one attribute

DirContext ldapCtx = new InitialDirContext(ldapProps)
ldapCtx.search("", ldapFilter, null).each{ldapUser->
    def ldapAttr = ldapUser.getAttributes().get(attr)
    attrValues = ldapAttr?.getAll()?.collect{it.toString()}
}
ldapCtx.close()
println "found values: $attrValues"
```